# ASP.NET LINQ query DbSet.Join() does not work

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I try to run this code here, in ASP.NET Entity Framework 7. The target is to have the most efficient solution here which should be a JOIN if the database.

```
public async Task<List<Building>> GetAllAsync(string commaSeparatedBuildingIDs)
    {
        var buildingRefIDs = commaSeparatedBuildingIDs.Split(",").ToList();

            return await semiSoftDbContext.Buildings
            .Join(buildingRefIDs, building => building.ReferenceId, refID => refID, (building, id) => building)
            .ToListAsync();

    }
```

I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Join(
> inner: __p_0,
> outerKeySelector: building => building.ReferenceId,
> innerKeySelector: refID => refID,
> resultSelector: (building, id) => building)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.`

I already have tried several variations of join and read through the internet, but it says that ASP.Net should work with Join().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not join here (assuming you are using Entity Framework - AFAIK it does not handle quite a lot of operations with local collections, like joins), use `Where` with `Contains`:

```cs
return await semiSoftDbContext.Buildings
   .Where(b => buildingRefIDs.Contains(b.ReferenceId))
   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: but the solution of "Where - Contains" is O(n²) if I am not mistaken (?) where join would only be O(n) because it is based on a hash function. How could we achieve O(n) instead?

Comment: @MaxAigner in this case `Where` will be translated into SQL (most likely into `WHERE .. IN (...)`) and it is up to database how to handle that. I highly doubt that there would be such huge performance difference. Check the generated SQL and compare the execution plan with the SQL you can write using `JOIN`.

Comment: Ok so I will test it as soon as I have the time.